# Does IPTable/Netfilter eat up ephemeral ports

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I wanted to understand more about Netfilter architecture. Let's say I have a machine with 3 IPs. I configure one IP to SNAT to all 3 IPs in round robin. Can I open more than 64k connections from that IP?

Answer (score 1):

No, because every outgoing connection gets mapped to a source port on the one public-facing address. And there are only 64K of those.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, this scenario is possible:
Let's say I have two internal IPs, IP1 and IP2 both public facing
I setup SNAT rules from IP2 to IP1 for some reason
I created a TCP connection from a port in IP2, that got NAT to IP1 and now linux thinks I'm using IP1 only (unaware of IP2 and it's port used)
I remove the IPTable entry, and create another TCP connection from the same port in IP2, that should work as well

Is this understanding right?

Comment: I'm talking about the reverse scenario, where you are making connections from 1 IP and NATing to 3 public facing IPs - does this overcome port limit?

Comment: I see. Sorry, I misunderstood. Sounds like you're still limited to 64K ports though, since again every connection has to be mapped back to the 1 initial source IP address.

Comment: that's where my actual doubt is, as Netfilter rewrites the flow, where is the entry maintained to map back?

Comment: Netfilter maintains the mapping. It has to, so it can send replies back to the originating address and port.

Comment: can it be that the socket source address is rewritten to be the NAT address (If both IPs are in the same system and there is no forwarding involved)?